# Wireguard Error "Unable to create network adapter"

Tags: windows-10, networking, drivers, wireguard

I created a Wireguard server, but can't get it running on my personal Windows 10 PC. When I try to activate the tunnel using the app, I can see a Wireguard network adapter appearing in the Device Manager for a short period, and then Wireguard fails, saying "*Couldn't create network adapter*".

**What I did:**

1. I tried connecting from many different devices (iOS, MacOS, Windows 10 laptop, Windows 8 PC) with all of my configs working just fine, so I am pretty sure that client-server configuration is not the issue, and the problem is with my OS.
2. I tried to inspect the traffic with wireshark and cant even see a handshake, so indeed Wireguard apparently fails yet before creating the connector.
3. I tried reseting Windows Network settings.
4. I tried deleting WAN miniport from network adapters, which however once again appeared in the list shorlty after.
5. I also tried launching wireguard from elevated console using >wireguard /installtunnelservice "C:\config_path.conf", which resulted in the very same error.
6. Of couse, I tried doing everything as admin user, with WG also being installed under the admin.
7. I tried older Wireguard versions (4.x)
8. I tried cleaning my registry using Revo and Ccleaner
9. Finally, I noticed a strange error, when installing a different software (npcap, if that matters), which might inidcate something. When installing this software, I had the wireguard app uninstalled. This software was looking through the driver packages avaliable on my system. At some point it found the driver package, subscribed by Wireguard LLC (which, once again, I thought was completely uninstalled), and failed with the following error log:

**NpCap installation failed due to Wireguard network adapter driver package**

```
[00004D70] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 <-- executeCommand

[00004D70] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 --> getInfNamesFromPnpUtilOutput

[00004D70] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 <-- getInfNamesFromPnpUtilOutput

[00004D70] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 <-- ClearDriverStore

[00004D70] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 <-- _tmain: succeed, nStatus = 0.

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 --> wmain

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 _tmain: executing, argv[1] = -n.

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 _tmain: executing, argv[2] = -iw.

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 --> InstallWFPCallout

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 --> GetWFPCalloutInfFilePath

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 lpFilename = C:\Program Files\Npcap\NPCAP_wfp.inf

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 <-- GetWFPCalloutInfFilePath

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 --> isFileExist

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 FindFirstFile: succeed, szFileFullPath = C:\Program Files\Npcap\NPCAP_wfp.inf.

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 <-- isFileExist

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 LaunchINFSectionEx: executing, szCmd = C:\Program Files\Npcap\NPCAP_wfp.inf,DefaultInstall,,36,N.

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 <-- InstallWFPCallout

[00001F88] 2023-09-28 14:45:20 <-- _tmain: succeed, nStatus = 0.

[00002E4C] 2023-09-28 14:45:21 --> wmain

[00002E4C] 2023-09-28 14:45:21 _tmain: executing, argv[1] = -n.

[00002E4C] 2023-09-28 14:45:21 _tmain: executing, argv[2] = -i2.

[00002E4C] 2023-09-28 14:45:21 --> InstallDriver

[00002E4C] 2023-09-28 14:45:21 --> GetServiceInfFilePath

[00002E4C] 2023-09-28 14:45:21 lpFilename = C:\Program Files\Npcap\NPCAP.inf

[00002E4C] 2023-09-28 14:45:21 <-- GetServiceInfFilePath

[00002E4C] 2023-09-28 14:45:21 --> InstallSpecifiedComponent

[00002E4C] 2023-09-28 14:45:21 --> HrGetINetCfg

[00002E4C] 2023-09-28 14:45:21 CoCreateInstance: error, hr = 0x8007045a.

[00002E4C] 2023-09-28 14:45:21 <-- HrGetINetCfg

[00002E4C] 2023-09-28 14:45:21 Error 0x8007045a: Couldn't the get notify object interface.

Possible cause:

Failed to initalize DLL (DLL).
```

Apart from it, there are very little diagnostic messages I was able to find on my machine, but here they are

**Wireguard app logs**

```
2023-10-02 13:48:56.797: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Starting WireGuard/0.5.3 (Windows 10.0.19045; amd64)

2023-10-02 13:48:56.797: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Watching network interfaces

2023-10-02 13:48:56.799: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Resolving DNS names

2023-10-02 13:48:56.799: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Creating network adapter

2023-10-02 13:48:56.876: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Using existing driver 0.10

2023-10-02 13:48:56.883: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Creating adapter

2023-10-02 13:49:11.897: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Timed out waiting for device query: Operation timeout. (Code 0x00000102)

2023-10-02 13:49:11.897: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Failed to setup adapter (problem code: 0x38, ntstatus: 0x0): Device not ready. (Code 0x000010DF)

2023-10-02 13:49:11.910: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Unable to create network adapter: Error creating adapter: The device is not ready for use.

2023-10-02 13:49:11.910: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Shutting down

2023-10-02 13:49:11.911: [MGR] [koldi-desktop] Tunnel service tracker finished
```

**Windows Event Viewer logs**

```
10/2/2023 1:48:56 PM - Information A service was installed in the system.Service Name: WireGuard Tunnel: koldi-desktop

Service File Name: "C:\Program Files\WireGuard\wireguard.exe" /tunnelservice "C:\Program Files\WireGuard\Data\Configurations\koldi-desktop.conf.dpapi"

10/2/2023 1:48:56 PM - Error The Network Setup service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 6 time(s).

10/2/2023 1:49:11 PM - Error The WireGuard Tunnel: koldi-desktop service terminated with the following service-specific error:

The system cannot find the path specified.
```

---

An important update, which seems to be getting me even closer to the root of the problem. I tried installing the older version of WireGuard, which gave me a more complete log in the app itself, and also I manage to trace this same error in Windows/INF/setupapi.dev.log

**New Wireguard log**

```
2023-10-05 14:55:45.568: [MGR] Starting WireGuard/0.4 (Windows 10.0.19045; amd64)
2023-10-05 14:55:45.573: [MGR] Starting UI process for user ‘koldi@DESKTOP-TN3C3LQ’ for session 1
2023-10-05 14:55:46.128: [MGR] An update is available
2023-10-05 14:56:01.655: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Starting WireGuard/0.4 (Windows 10.0.19045; amd64)
2023-10-05 14:56:01.655: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Watching network interfaces
2023-10-05 14:56:01.657: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Resolving DNS names
2023-10-05 14:56:01.657: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Creating network adapter
2023-10-05 14:56:01.660: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] [Wintun] WintunCreateAdapter: Creating adapter
2023-10-05 14:56:01.751: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] [Wintun] SelectDriver: Installing driver 0.13
2023-10-05 14:56:01.751: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] [Wintun] SelectDriver: Extracting driver
2023-10-05 14:56:01.752: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] [Wintun] SelectDriver: Installing driver
2023-10-05 14:56:12.010: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] [Wintun] RegistryQueryStringWait: Timeout waiting for registry value \REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0003\NetCfgInstanceId (status: 0x102)
2023-10-05 14:56:12.010: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] [Wintun] WintunCreateAdapter: Failed to get \REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0003\NetCfgInstanceId
2023-10-05 14:56:12.020: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Unable to create network adapter: Error creating interface: The system cannot find the file specified.
2023-10-05 14:56:12.020: [TUN] [koldi-desktop] Shutting down
2023-10-05 14:56:12.021: [MGR] [koldi-desktop] Tunnel service tracker finished
```

**Windows/INF/setupapi.dev.log**

```
>>>  [SetupCopyOEMInf - C:\Windows\Temp\a8cedcbd9cbc2dde94b3b86485a8b9e4adf1ad930f68fbc0c50b62b55965774a\wintun.inf]
>>>  Section start 2023/10/05 14:56:01.754
      cmd: "C:\Program Files\WireGuard\wireguard.exe" /tunnelservice "C:\Program Files\WireGuard\Data\Configurations\koldi-desktop.conf.dpapi"
     inf: Copy style: 0x00000000
     sto: {Setup Import Driver Package: C:\Windows\Temp\a8cedcbd9cbc2dde94b3b86485a8b9e4adf1ad930f68fbc0c50b62b55965774a\wintun.inf} 14:56:01.755
     inf:      Provider: WireGuard LLC
     inf:      Class GUID: {4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
     inf:      Driver Version: 08/02/2021,0.13.0.0
     inf:      Catalog File: wintun.cat
     ump:      Import flags: 0x00000009
     pol:      {Driver package policy check} 14:56:01.774
     pol:      {Driver package policy check - exit(0x00000000)} 14:56:01.775
     sto:      {Stage Driver Package: C:\Windows\Temp\a8cedcbd9cbc2dde94b3b86485a8b9e4adf1ad930f68fbc0c50b62b55965774a\wintun.inf} 14:56:01.775
     inf:           {Query Configurability: C:\Windows\Temp\a8cedcbd9cbc2dde94b3b86485a8b9e4adf1ad930f68fbc0c50b62b55965774a\wintun.inf} 14:56:01.781
     inf:                Driver package 'wintun.inf' is configurable.
     inf:           {Query Configurability: exit(0x00000000)} 14:56:01.782
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COMMIT} 14:56:01.783
     flq:                Copying 'C:\Windows\Temp\a8cedcbd9cbc2dde94b3b86485a8b9e4adf1ad930f68fbc0c50b62b55965774a\wintun.cat' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{64b59a7f-4019-b148-93f6-19c3178c14ce}\wintun.cat'.
     flq:                Copying 'C:\Windows\Temp\a8cedcbd9cbc2dde94b3b86485a8b9e4adf1ad930f68fbc0c50b62b55965774a\wintun.inf' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{64b59a7f-4019-b148-93f6-19c3178c14ce}\wintun.inf'.
     flq:                Copying 'C:\Windows\Temp\a8cedcbd9cbc2dde94b3b86485a8b9e4adf1ad930f68fbc0c50b62b55965774a\wintun.sys' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{64b59a7f-4019-b148-93f6-19c3178c14ce}\wintun.sys'.
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COMMIT - exit(0x00000000)} 14:56:01.803
     sto:           {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT VALIDATE} 14:56:01.804
     sig:                Driver package catalog is valid.
     sig:                {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE} 14:56:01.819
     sig:                     Key      = wintun.inf
     sig:                     FilePath = C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{64b59a7f-4019-b148-93f6-19c3178c14ce}\wintun.inf
     sig:                     Catalog  = C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{64b59a7f-4019-b148-93f6-19c3178c14ce}\wintun.cat
     sig:                     Success: File is signed in catalog.
     sig:                {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE exit(0x00000000)} 14:56:01.824
     sto:           {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT VALIDATE: exit(0x00000000)} 14:56:01.826
     sig:           Signer Score  = 0x0D000005 (WHQL)
     sig:           Signer Name   = Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher
     sig:           Submission ID = 58177670_14147300089215136_1152921505693731132
     sto:           {Core Driver Package Import: wintun.inf_amd64_d97096a68f999890} 14:56:01.828
     sto:                {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT BEGIN} 14:56:01.828
     sto:                {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT BEGIN: exit(0x00000000)} 14:56:01.828
     cpy:                {Copy Directory: C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{64b59a7f-4019-b148-93f6-19c3178c14ce}} 14:56:01.828
     cpy:                     Target Path = C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wintun.inf_amd64_d97096a68f999890
     cpy:                {Copy Directory: exit(0x00000000)} 14:56:01.830
     idb:                {Register Driver Package: C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wintun.inf_amd64_d97096a68f999890\wintun.inf} 14:56:01.831
     idb:                     Created driver package object 'wintun.inf_amd64_d97096a68f999890' in DRIVERS database node.
     idb:                     Created driver INF file object 'oem11.inf' in DRIVERS database node.
     idb:                     Registered driver package 'wintun.inf_amd64_d97096a68f999890' with 'oem11.inf'.
     idb:                {Register Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 14:56:01.833
     idb:                {Publish Driver Package: C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wintun.inf_amd64_d97096a68f999890\wintun.inf} 14:56:01.833
     idb:                     Activating driver package 'wintun.inf_amd64_d97096a68f999890'.
     cpy:                     Published 'wintun.inf_amd64_d97096a68f999890\wintun.inf' to 'oem11.inf'.
     idb:                     Indexed 2 device IDs for 'wintun.inf_amd64_d97096a68f999890'.
     sto:                     Flushed driver database node 'DRIVERS'. Time = 15 ms
     sto:                     Flushed driver database node 'SYSTEM'. Time = 16 ms
     idb:                {Publish Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 14:56:01.857
     sto:                {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT END} 14:56:01.858
     dvi:                     Flushed all driver package files to disk. Time = 0 ms
     sig:                     Installed catalog 'wintun.cat' as 'oem11.cat'.
     sto:                {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT END: exit(0x00000000)} 14:56:01.873
     sto:           {Core Driver Package Import: exit(0x00000000)} 14:56:01.873
     sto:      {Stage Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 14:56:01.874
!    dvi:      Unable to locate device 'ROOT\NET\0000'. cr = 0x0D
     sto: {Setup Import Driver Package - exit (0x00000000)} 14:56:01.920
     inf: Driver Store Path: C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wintun.inf_amd64_d97096a68f999890\wintun.inf
     inf: Published Inf Path: C:\Windows\INF\oem11.inf
<<<  Section end 2023/10/05 14:56:01.922
<<<  [Exit status: SUCCESS]


>>>  [Configure Driver Package - c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\wintun.inf_amd64_d97096a68f999890\wintun.inf]
>>>  Section start 2023/10/05 14:56:01.973
      cmd: "C:\Program Files\WireGuard\wireguard.exe" /tunnelservice "C:\Program Files\WireGuard\Data\Configurations\koldi-desktop.conf.dpapi"
     sto: Source Filter  = Wintun.Install
     sto: Target Filter  = ROOT\NET\0000
     inf: Class GUID     = {4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
     inf: Class Options  = Configurable
     inf: {Configure Driver: Wintun Userspace Tunnel}
     inf:      Section Name = Wintun.Install
     inf:      {Configure Device: ROOT\NET\0000}
     inf:      {Configure Device: exit(0x00000000)}
     inf: {Configure Driver: exit(0x00000000)}
<<<  Section end 2023/10/05 14:56:01.978
<<<  [Exit status: SUCCESS]


>>>  [Restart Device - ROOT\NET\0000]
>>>  Section start 2023/10/05 14:56:01.979
      cmd: "C:\Program Files\WireGuard\wireguard.exe" /tunnelservice "C:\Program Files\WireGuard\Data\Configurations\koldi-desktop.conf.dpapi"
     dvi: Device Status: 0x01802001
     dvi: {Restarting Devices} 14:56:01.979
     dvi:      Start: ROOT\NET\0000
!    dvi:      Device 'ROOT\NET\0000' pending start: Device has problem: 0x38 (CM_PROB_NEED_CLASS_CONFIG), problem status: 0x00000000.
     dvi: {Restarting Devices exit} 14:56:02.001
<<<  Section end 2023/10/05 14:56:02.001
<<<  [Exit status: SUCCESS]


>>>  [Delete Device - ROOT\NET\0000]
>>>  Section start 2023/10/05 14:56:12.010
      cmd: "C:\Program Files\WireGuard\wireguard.exe" /tunnelservice "C:\Program Files\WireGuard\Data\Configurations\koldi-desktop.conf.dpapi"
     dvi: Query-and-Remove succeeded
<<<  Section end 2023/10/05 14:56:12.019
<<<  [Exit status: SUCCESS]
```

As you can see, it seems to successfuly create the WinTun network adapter, but than doesn't manage to find it on the registry (`ROOT\NET\0000` device corresponds to unknown device AFAIK) or something like this. Probably it is possible to manually reinstall wintun somehow.

I am starting to lose hope, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Probably an important update. When wireguard is installed, in Windows Registry Editor under `HKLM\Drivers\DriverDatabase\DriverInfFiles` I can see `oem11.inf`, which is Wireguard (I know that from running pnputil). Also under  `HKLM\Drivers\DriverDatabase\DriverPackages` I can see a file, corresponding to `oem11.inf` `Active` field. 

This is a very random guess, but shouldnt these files be under `HKLM\System\DriverDatabase`? The two lists seem exclusive, and since NpCap gave me an error of not being able to find the driver package, probably that is the issue? How do I proceed in such case?

Comment: The error "The system cannot find the path specified" does give some support to your guess. Uninstalling wireguard completely using an uninstaller like Revo might be a good idea, then reinstall it carefully.

Comment: @harrymc Tried doing the most complete uninstall, clearing the registry and all other leftover files. That didn't help unfortunately. 
Also I believe, that despite my previous comment, the registry keys are correct. I compared them with the ones on another Windows10 laptop with wireguard installed, and they look the same

Comment: Your problem might be the same as in [this link](https://blog.tommyku.com/blog/fixing-wireguard-windows-unable-to-start-as-service/) where it was caused by missing permissions on a single file when the logged-in user account was not administrator. Let me know if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @harrymc Didn't help either. I seem to have traced the problem even further, looks like the issue is with wintun driver, but I still don't know how to solve it. I updated my original question with new logs, would be really grateful if you could look at them and propose something!

Comment: Might there be a conflict with another installed VPN? Also, in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/oz2awj/unable_to_create_network_adapter/) a solution was to install an older WireGuard [version 0.4](https://www.wingetgui.com/apps?id=WireGuard.WireGuard&v=0.4).

Comment: @harrymc Yeah, already tried that version. Didn't solve the issue, but provided the new log, highlighting wintun error, I talked about. No other VPN on my machine either.